# Download binary file to documents directory (IOS). How?

Tags: ios, xcode, url, download, binary

I want to store a binary file in my IPad-Documents-Directory.

```
 - (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection
 NSString *txt = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding: ?????] autorelease];
 //write to disk
 file = ...;
 [txt writeToFile:file atomically:NO encoding:??? error:NULL];
```

So, now I get a binary file, that is different from the original one. I assume, it is the encoding or Bigendian / LittleEndian; 
If I use an Ascii-File this method works without any problem.
What should I do? Not using NSString? What encoding? Tried severals. None worked.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (and should) save NSData object directly to the disc without converting it to NSString:

```
[responseData writeToFile:file atomically:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are storing binary data in an `NSString` object and writing it out to the file system, while instead I think you should load that binary data into an `NSData` object and then say:

```
[myNSDataObject writeToFile:myFilePath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Thank you, I used Vladimirs solution but I guess yours is basically the same and would also work ...